# Error connecting from pyspark to mongodb with password

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running following pyspark code with connection to mongodb

```
sparkConf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("MongoSparkConnectorTour").set("spark.app.id", "MongoSparkConnectorTour")

# If executed via pyspark, sc is already instantiated
sc = SparkContext(conf=sparkConf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# create and load dataframe from MongoDB URI
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")\
                    .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", config.MONGO_URL_AUTH + "/spark.times")\
                    .load()
```

inside Docker image with

```
CMD [ "spark-submit" \
    , "--conf", "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://root:example@mongodb:27017/spark.times" \
    , "--conf", "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://root:example@mongodb:27017/spark.output" \
    , "--packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1" \
    , "./spark.py" ]
```

`config.MONGO_URL_AUTH` is `mongodb://root:example@mongodb:27017`

but I'm getting exception on run:

```
db_1           | 2019-10-09T13:44:34.354+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn4] Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user 'root@spark'
db_1           | 2019-10-09T13:44:34.378+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn4] SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for root on spark from client 172.22.0.4:49302 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user "root" for db "spark"


pyspark_1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
pyspark_1      |   File "/home/ubuntu/./spark.py", line 35, in <module>
pyspark_1      |     .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", config.MONGO_URL_AUTH + "/spark.times")\
pyspark_1      |   File "/home/ubuntu/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
pyspark_1      |     return self._df(self._jreader.load())
pyspark_1      |   File "/home/ubuntu/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
pyspark_1      |   File "/home/ubuntu/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
pyspark_1      |     return f(*a, **kw)
pyspark_1      |   File "/home/ubuntu/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
pyspark_1      | py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.load.
pyspark_1      | : com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='root', source='spark', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
pyspark_1      |    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:173)
```

everything in this setup works flawlessly if I don't use user and password in mongodb docker and just connect with `mongodb://mongodb:27017` address, and just with using `pymongo` I can connect with password, something is wrong with my spark to mongodb configuration when password is used and I can't understand what is wrong.

setup for mongodb (part of docker-compose file):

```
  db:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    networks:
        miasnet:
          aliases:
            - "miasdb"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: spark
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - /data/db:/data/db
```

Comment: What is your setup for MongoDB?

Comment: @RemcoBuddelmeijer added to question

Comment: try this set("spark.mongodb.input.database", dbName) in your spark conf & use an escape character if there are any special characters in your password

Comment: @SarathChandraVema doesn't help, same error with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo reads:

> **`MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME`, `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`**
>
> These variables, used in conjunction, create a new user and set that user's password. This user is created in the **admin authentication database** and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.

You don't specify the authentication database, so [mongo uses current database by default](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-authenticationdatabase) - `spark` in your case.

You need to specify "admin" auth database in the connection string:

```
spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://root:example@mongodb:27017/spark.times?authSource=admin
spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://root:example@mongodb:27017/spark.output?authSource=admin
```